# What should I do to limit the amount of characters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing an app to display the posts from a WordPress account, but some of those posts are so long, so I need to limit the amount of characters to display only let's say 300 characters and also implement a button "read more..."

is there any angular way ?

or

how can I achieve that ?

```
angular.module('urbanet.app.service', [])

.service('FreshlyPressed', function($http) {
  return {
    getBlogs: function($scope) {
      $http.jsonp('https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/freshly-pressed?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .success(function(result) {
          $scope.posts = result.posts;
        });
    }
  }
})

.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, $log, FreshlyPressed) {
  $scope.posts = [];
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {

    FreshlyPressed.getBlogs($scope);
    console.log('PRESSED');

  }
  $scope.doRefresh();
});
```

there is the code I am using.

Comment: Doesn't the data already include the post `excerpt` property? On self hosted wordpress that's part of the REST API output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/LVGjwq)

**Updated** my answer with a directive, but codepen is doing maintenance. I will try to save it tomorrow.

```
<!-- html -->
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <div id="{{$index}}" limit="{{limit}}"></div>
</div>
```

```
// module.directive
function limit () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A'
  , replace: false
  , link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      var postText
        , buttonText = 'Read More'
        , limit = +attrs.limit
        , span = angular.element('<span/>')
        , button = 
            angular.element('<button/>')
              .on('click', function () {
                limit = limit < Infinity 
                  ? Infinity 
                  : +attrs.limit

                buttonText = limit < Infinity
                  ? 'Read More'
                  : 'Close'

                elem.init()
              })

      elem.init = function () {
        postText = scope.posts[attrs.id].text.substr(0, limit)
        button.text(buttonText)
        elem.append(span).text(postText).append(button)
      }
      elem.init()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not bad azium :), but when you are using angular, recommend using methods that work in real time (these variables are useful in a future) and angular will handle the events (click, change, etc...).

Comment: Yeah using `$watch` definitely makes sense. I got this idea from the docs actually https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-adds-event-listeners

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `limitTo` filter like you would with an array in angular

```
<p>
   <span ng-if="showall">{{postbody}}</span>
   <span ng-if="!showall">{{postbody | limitTo:300}}</span>
   <div ng-if="postbody.length > 300" ng-click="showall = !showall">read more...</div>
</p>
```

Comment: Not super elegant, but this works. Would be better packed into a directive, also it kind of depends on how the OP intends to display the post upon button click.

Comment: Absolutely. However, the question seemed to just be about how to limit the text body, so I contained my answer to that. Certainly adding a layer of abstraction would make it more portable.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a simple text, you can create a filter?

```
module.filter('CutText', function() {
    return function (text, maxlength){
        return text.length > maxlength ? text.substr(0, maxlength) + "..." : text;
    };
});
//<div ng-bind="scope_variable | CutText:300"></div>
```

However, if you want to get what you mention, you can create a directive that adds a button element "Read more ..."

**Directive:**

```
module.directive('moreLess', ["$compile", function($compile){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var text = element.text(), max = +attrs.moreLess, button, more;

            scope.show = false;

            if(text.length > max){

                button = angular.element("<a/>").attr({"ng-click": "show = !show", "href": "#"});
                more = angular.element("<span />").attr("ng-show", "show").text(text.substr(max));

                element.text(text.substr(0, max)).append(more).append(button);

                var newScope = scope.$new();

                $compile(element.contents())(newScope);

                newScope.$watch("show", function(show){
                    button.text(!show ? "more..." : "less");
                });
            }

        }
    };
}]);
//
//HTML <div more-less="32">Big Text..........</div>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/2Ts4URPsysZtaG84YoZA?p=preview

Comment: Cool, I was writing a directive but taking a slightly different approach. I like yours better, but `$compile(element.contents())(scope);` crashes codepen

Comment: Edited. I changed the line, and I created a new scope only to that element, since previously it took in the parent element

Comment: I just posted my directive. Thanks for introducing me to `angular.element`. I didn't use any extra directives, and didn't use `$compile` either. Thanks for the inspiration

Answer (score 1):

So basically something like

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts>
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    {{ post.text | limitTo: 300 }}
    <button ng-click="viewPost(post.id)">
        Read More
    </button>
</div>
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

wordpress already provides you with an `excerpt` property which is an abbreviation of the post....typically set by word count within wordpress admin settings.

This property exists in the sample url in question

All you would need for "read more" is link to full post